# bleed through effect in ipad

Tags: animation, ipad

i want to know is there any animation bleed through effect in ipad??????

Comment: there is no animation name Bleed through is find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That iBooks page-curl effect is using a private API ([CAFilter](http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=CAFilter)). You can't use it in your own app if you target for AppStore.

(The ["bleed through"](http://www.kofax.com/glossary/Bleed-Through/) is part of the feature of that private page-curl effect.)